# HTML5 image on hexagon not loading image but drawing hexagon black

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have been playing around with HTML5 canvases latterly and been trying to draw images onto hexagons. I have been using KineticJS to do this and the following is the code that I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Request System</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

    <script>            
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 578,
            height: 600
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        logo = new Image();
        logo.onload = function() {
            var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
                x: stage.width()/2,
                y: stage.height()/2,
                sides: 6,
                radius: 200,
                fill: {image: logo},
                stroke: 'black',
            });

            // add the shape to the layer
            layer.add(hexagon);

            // add the layer to the stage
            stage.add(layer);
        };
        logo.src = "https://hiveradio.net/api/icebreath/?func=get&mod=cover&artist=NIIC";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It draws a black hexagon but no image on it, any help it greatly welcomed.

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle with the code http://jsfiddle.net/z5pLF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fillPatternImage` instead of `fill`:

```
var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
        x: stage.width()/2,
        y: stage.height()/2,
        sides: 6,
        radius: 200,
        fillPatternImage: logo,
        fillPatternOffset: {x:250, y:250},
        stroke: 'black',
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5pLF/3/

Comment: How would I go about also resizing the image so if fits more in?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out `fillPatternScale: {x:0.70, y:0.70}` Thanks lots!